# Directly accessing files through reverse proxy

Tags: security, network-share, authorization

With my web app I've got to provide files to third party apis that unfortunately only accept file names. The files can be located anywhere, local or on network shares. The files are actually stored on a network share, where only a system account has access due to security.

The web app (running with this system account) checks authorisation, reads the files and uploads the data as payload of the http response via a reverse proxy to the client.

On the client, the files are saved to a local directory and then this file location is given to the third party api.

The problem is that the local storage is limited and the amount of data is quite large. Also, performance is not really as expected by the users. Lastly, our IT-sec accepts this as a temporary solution, as no data should be stored on the local machines.

Is there a way to securely grant access to the network share (nfs protocoll). Something like a reverse proxy for nfs? Or how are problems like this solved?

Cheers,

Jan